# Is it possible (natively) to have a nested form in Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe2, c++builder-xe2

I'm building an application where I'd like to have "nested" forms inside of one main form, but I can't figure out how to do this with any of the components.

I'm sure I could pretty easily code some similar functionality, but I didn't want to go down that road until I was sure there wasn't a "built-in" option/property for this.

I'm using the C++Builder version, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't make much of a difference here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm pretty new to the tool and couldn't find anything about this online

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "nested forms"? Do you mean like the old style `MDI` forms that only exist inside their parent window? Also, are you talking about  a `VCL` application, or `FireMonkey`?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. By "forms", I basically mean windows. And by nested windows, I mean windows that exist strictly within another window, which they cannot exit. And so that I could click on the background window ("form"), and it would not move in front of the nested (or child) window. And if I moved the background window, the "nested" windows would move accordingly. Like a toolbar in Photoshop, that sort of behavior. Also, this is a VCL application. I'm unfamiliar with the old style MDI forms.

Comment: Oh, hey, look at that. You answered my question there just with the letters MDI! "Create new MDI Application". Nice. Thanks. you should post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `VCL` applications, you're probably looking for [MDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Set your parent form's `FormStyle` to `fsMDIForm`, and each of your child window's `FormStyle` to `fsMDIChild`.

You should be aware, though, that `MDI` has been deprecated for years now, and is not used by most applications. Even MS Office has forsaken the MDI interface for more than a decade, implementing something internally that mimics it instead.